# Heatmap like plot for categorical variables in bokeh using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, heatmap, bokeh

I plotted categorical data by converting classes into numbers (taking inspiration from another stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227475/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables-in-seaborn)). Is it possible to do something similar in bokeh (something like this [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html))? 
The main advantage with sns is minimal processing of dataframe. While reading the example above, it would be rather problematic for me to label the axes if I create a function. What I'm essentially aiming for is a function which will create a heatmap like plot by taking index on one axis and columns on another axis.

My current code:

```
import gzip, sys, getopt, shlex, subprocess, os
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Table, Math, TikZ, Axis, Plot, Figure, Package
from pylatex.utils import italic, escape_latex
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from pylatex import Document, Section, Figure, SubFigure, NoEscape
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv('postq.csv')
df = df.groupby(['sample', 'tot.seq', 'module'])['status'].apply(', '.join).unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
mapping = {'PASS': 1, 'WARN': 2, 'FAIL': 3}
df = df.replace({'Basic Statistics': mapping, 'Per base sequence quality': mapping, 'Per tile sequence quality': mapping, 'Per sequence quality scores': mapping, 'Per base sequence content': mapping, 'Per sequence GC content': mapping, 'Per base N content': mapping, 'Sequence Length Distribution': mapping, 'Sequence Duplication Levels': mapping, 'Overrepresented sequences': mapping, 'Adapter Content': mapping,'Kmer Content': mapping})
df = df.drop('tot.seq', 1)
df = df.set_index('sample')
f, ax = plt.subplots()
hm = sns.heatmap(data = df, cmap="Pastel2", ax=ax, cbar=False)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.7, box.height])
legend_ax = f.add_axes([.7, .5, 1, .1])
legend_ax.axis('off')
colors = plt.cm.Pastel2(np.linspace(0, 1, len(mapping)))
patches = [mpatches.Patch(facecolor=c, edgecolor=c) for c in colors]
legend = legend_ax.legend(patches,
    sorted(mapping),
    handlelength=0.8, loc='lower left')
for t in legend.get_texts():
    t.set_ha("left")
f.savefig('output.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

And snippet of the csv file used as input:

```
"sample","module","status","tot.seq","seq.length","pct.gc","pct.dup"
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Basic Statistics","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per base sequence quality","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per tile sequence quality","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per sequence quality scores","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per base sequence content","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per sequence GC content","WARN","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Per base N content","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Sequence Length Distribution","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Sequence Duplication Levels","FAIL","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Overrepresented sequences","WARN","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Adapter Content","PASS","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_1","Kmer Content","FAIL","19823396","62",51,51.06
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Basic Statistics","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per base sequence quality","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per tile sequence quality","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per sequence quality scores","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per base sequence content","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per sequence GC content","FAIL","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Per base N content","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Sequence Length Distribution","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Sequence Duplication Levels","WARN","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Overrepresented sequences","FAIL","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Adapter Content","PASS","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435936_cleaned_2","Kmer Content","FAIL","19823396","62",51,43.33
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Basic Statistics","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per base sequence quality","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per tile sequence quality","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per sequence quality scores","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per base sequence content","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per sequence GC content","WARN","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Per base N content","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Sequence Length Distribution","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Sequence Duplication Levels","WARN","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Overrepresented sequences","WARN","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Adapter Content","PASS","23937659","62",50,48.53
"ERR435937_cleaned_1","Kmer Content","FAIL","23937659","62",50,48.53
```

My current plot looks something like this(legend order is slightly messed up): [image]

Comment: I have been trying for days to find a good way to create heatmaps of categorical data in plotly, bokeh, seaborn (this last one seems to be the only one that allows that to be done without going crazy) but nothing that gets even close to a straightforward solution

Comment: @Siddharth let me see I got it straight, you want to reproduce something similar you did with seaborn with bokeh? Is that right? The problem would be set the labels in a function?

Comment: @ReinholdN - I asked this question 5 years ago....so my memory is a bit fuzzy. The original question was to replicate seaborn like categorical heatmap in Bokeh. If I were to do it now, I would have used Altair/Vega.

Comment: Well I use heatmap with bokeh and it is quiet handy to be honest. The question came up to the top because someone made a comment. If you still consider use bokeh let me know and I will through a decent example here for you.

Comment: For the sake of posterity - I guess it is better for you to answer it. I can mark it as an accepted answer so people can reference it in future.