# How to select and order values in seaborn legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to only include certain values in a seaborn heatmap legend. Specifically, I have a "nan" category that I don't want to see in the legend.

I am trying to plot ward movements for patients in a hospital as a kind of categorical heatmap, with different colours representing different wards. I have borrowed from this code [heatmap-like plot, but for categorical variables in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227475/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables-in-seaborn) to configure my input table for the heatmap. Blank cells mean the patient was not in the hospital on those dates.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd

data = {'12/3': [np.nan, 'Ward_B', np.nan],
        '13/3': [np.nan, 'Ward_B', np.nan],
        '14/3': [np.nan, 'Ward_B', 'ED'],
        '15/3': ['ED', 'Ward_A', 'Ward_C'],
        '16/3': ['ED', 'Ward_A', 'Ward_C'],
        '17/3': ['Ward_A', 'Ward_A', 'Ward_C'],
        '18/3': ['Ward_A', np.nan, 'Ward_C'],
        '19/3': ['Ward_A', np.nan, 'Ward_A'],
        '20/3': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Ward_A']}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['12/3',
                                    '13/3',
                                    '14/3',
                                    '15/3',
                                    '16/3',
                                    '17/3',
                                    '18/3',
                                    '19/3',
                                    '20/3'])

# Create dataframe of patient IDs
patient_codes_df = pd.DataFrame(['Patient_A', 'Patient_B', 'Patient_C'])
# change heading
patient_codes_df = patient_codes_df.rename(columns={0:'Patient'})
# Merge
df2 = pd.concat([patient_codes_df, df], axis=1)
# Make Patient column the index
df3 = df2.set_index('Patient')
df3
```

df3 is what my input data looks like.

And this is how I'm plotting the heatmap

```
value_to_int = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(pd.unique(df3.values.ravel()))}
n = len(value_to_int)

cmap = sns.color_palette("Accent", n) # set colours

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 2), dpi=300)

mask = df3.isnull()
ax = sns.heatmap(df3.replace(value_to_int), cmap=cmap, mask=mask, linewidths=0.1, linecolor='#b5b5b5') 

ax.set_ylabel('')

# modify colorbar:
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar 
r = colorbar.vmax - colorbar.vmin 
colorbar.set_ticks([colorbar.vmin + r / n * (0.5 + i) for i in range(n)])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(list(value_to_int.keys()))  
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

I would like to get rid of "nan" from the legend, and also re order so it goes in a sensible order like ED, Ward_A, Ward_B, Ward_C.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to drop the nans when you define `value_to_int`. The code you borrowed is good, but I guess the more straightforward way is to define your colors manually in a dictionary, then replace your data.frame with this while plotting:

```
lvls = {'ED': 0, 'Ward_A': 1, 'Ward_B': 2, 'Ward_C': 3}
cmap = sns.color_palette("Accent", len(lvls)) # set colours

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 2), dpi=300)
sns.heatmap(df3.replace(lvls),cmap=cmap,mask=df3.isnull(),linewidths=.1,
            linecolor='#b5b5b5',ax=ax)

colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar 
r = colorbar.vmax - colorbar.vmin
n = len(lvls)
colorbar.set_ticks([colorbar.vmin + r / n * (0.5 + i) for i in range(n)])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(list(lvls.keys()))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks more elegant than my solution of drawing my own legend from scratch. But I get an error in line 4 with your code - "NameError: name 'tcks' is not defined". I'm probably doing something stupid...

Comment: sorry about that.. thanks for the feedback. I was trying something and the tcks was kept. I have removed that argument, the code above should work now

Comment: Now I get error from line 7, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vmax'"

Comment: arh ok.. you did not call ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 2), dpi=300)```, ok i include that

Comment: Great that worked thanks! Is there a way to specify the order of the color bar?

Comment: thanks the purpose of the dictionary, lvls, so what is 0 is always bottom on the color, 3 is always on top.. and you have to assign the labels in the order, for example ```{ 'Ward_A': 0, 'Ward_B': 1, 'Ward_C': 2,'ED': 3}``` would have ward_A bottom ED top

Answer (score 0):

So one approach which worked was to remove the color bar and create my own legend manually:

```
# Define colours
cols = ["#ffff99", '#beaed4', '#fdc692', '#7fc97f', '#fd4396']

# Transform categorical variables into numbers for heatmap
value_to_int = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(pd.unique(df3.values.ravel()))}
n = len(value_to_int)
cmap = sns.color_palette(cols, n) # set colours

# Plot figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (8, 3), dpi=300)
sns.set(font_scale=1.27, style='whitegrid')
mask = df3.isnull()
ax = sns.heatmap(df3.replace(value_to_int),
                 cmap=cmap, mask=mask, linewidths=0.1, linecolor='#b5b5b5',
                 cbar=False, # Remove the color bar legend
                 xticklabels=2)

# Tweaking figire
ax.set_ylabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# Create a new legend
ED_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#beaed4', label='ED')
A_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#7fc97f', label='Ward A')
B_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#fd4396', label='Ward B')
C_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#3da1bf', label='Ward C')

ax.legend(handles=[ED_patch,A_patch,B_patch,C_patch],
         bbox_to_anchor=(1.22, 1),
         prop={'size': 12})
```