# Discrete colormap for multidimensional data with varying weights using python seaborn

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, seaborn, colormap

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sunday":    {'a1':0.1,'a2':0.15,'a4':0.05,'a6':0.1,'b2':0.05,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.2,'c1':0.15,'c4':0.15},
                   "Monday":    {'a2':0.05,'a3':0.15,'a5':0.25,'b1':0.05,'b3':0.1,'b4':0.1,'c3':0.1,'c5':0.05,'c7':0.15},
                   "Tuesday":   {'a1':0.2,'a3':0.15,'a6':0.05,'b2':0.35,'b3':0.05,'c1':0.1,'c4':0.1},
                   "Wednesday": {'a2':0.05,'a3':0.05,'a4':0.35,'a6':0.2,'b1':0.1,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.05,'c1':0.05,'c6':0.1},
                   "Thursday":  {'a1':0.25,'a3':0.05,'a4':0.3,'a5':0.05,'a6':0.1,'b1':0.05,'b4':0.05,'c2':0.1,'c4':0.05},
                   "Friday":    {'a1':0.1,'a2':0.15,'a5':0.1,'a7':0.05,'b2':0.05,'b1':0.15,'b4':0.2,'c3':0.05,'c4':0.05,'c5':0.05,'c7':0.05},
                   "Saturday":  {'a1':0.15,'a3':0.05,'b2':0.05,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.4,'c1':0.1,'c5':0.1,'c7':0.1}
                   }}
```

The keys in dictionaries for each day are categorical and they come in three general types a, b, c: each of them having some number of sub-types. There are 6 subtypes in a-type, 4 subtypes in b-type and 7 subtypes in c-type. The values in dictionaries, represent weights (importance). Not every observation (day), needs to have all possible sub-types present. Nan values in each observation (day) should be ignored (when plot is created).

I would like to visualize this data using a discrete colormap, similarly as it was done in this post: [heatmap-like plot, but for categorical variables in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227475/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables-in-seaborn). Their solution is very elegant but my problem is slightly more complicated, as I would also like to reflect the weight of each subtype—by the height of the rectangle that represents it (shown on y-axis). Weights for each day always sum to one. On the x-axis, I would like to have weekdays shown. And all subtypes with colors assigned to them should be shown on the colorbar on the right with their corresponding code names: 'a1',...,'a6', 'b1', ...,'b4','c1',...,'c7'.

Finally, I would like to use different colormaps to color different subtypes: for example, blues for a-types, greens for b-types and reds for c-types.

I would like to do this using Python Seaborn package but if you can suggest a better solution using a different package I don't mind using it instead.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a stacked bar graph with seaborn, you seem to need summed bars plotted on top of each other (see e.g. [this blogpost](https://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/)). That gets quite complex with 18 types.

With pandas plot, things are a bit easier, although some manipulation is needed:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sunday":    {'a1':0.1,'a2':0.15,'a4':0.05,'a6':0.1,'b2':0.05,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.2,'c1':0.15,'c4':0.15},
                   "Monday":    {'a2':0.05,'a3':0.15,'a5':0.25,'b1':0.05,'b3':0.1,'b4':0.1,'c3':0.1,'c5':0.05,'c7':0.15},
                   "Tuesday":   {'a1':0.2,'a3':0.15,'a6':0.05,'b2':0.35,'b3':0.05,'c1':0.1,'c4':0.1},
                   "Wednesday": {'a2':0.05,'a3':0.05,'a4':0.35,'a6':0.2,'b1':0.1,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.05,'c1':0.05,'c6':0.1},
                   "Thursday":  {'a1':0.25,'a3':0.05,'a4':0.3,'a5':0.05,'a6':0.1,'b1':0.05,'b4':0.05,'c2':0.1,'c4':0.05},
                   "Friday":    {'a1':0.1,'a2':0.15,'a5':0.1,'a7':0.05,'b2':0.05,'b1':0.15,'b4':0.2,'c3':0.05,'c4':0.05,'c5':0.05,'c7':0.05},
                   "Saturday":  {'a1':0.15,'a3':0.05,'b2':0.05,'b3':0.05,'b4':0.4,'c1':0.1,'c5':0.1,'c7':0.1}
                   })
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)  # replace NA with zeros
df2 = df.T  # switch rows and columns
df2 = df2.reindex(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1)  # reorder the columns
types = df2.columns
num_type = {letter: len([t for t in types if t[0] == letter]) for letter in 'abc'}
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0, figsize=(10, 5),
             color=[plt.cm.Blues_r(i / 7) for i in range(num_type['a'])]
                   + [plt.cm.Greens_r(i / 7) for i in range(num_type['b'])]
                   + [plt.cm.Reds_r(i / 7) for i in range(num_type['c'])])
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left') # legend outside the main plot
plt.tight_layout() # fit legend and labels
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Some of the manipulations needed to get a seaborn plot include converting the index to a named column (e.g. 'type') and converting the data to long form.

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.set_names(['type'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
types = sorted(np.unique(df['type']))
df_long = df.melt(var_name='day', value_name='weight', id_vars='type')
sns.barplot(x='day', y='weight', hue='type', hue_order=types, data=df_long)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. It's just perfect! Just one more question... is there a way to make the order of items identical in both, the graph and the colorbar on the side?

Comment: The easiest would be to invert the yaxis  with `plt.ylim(1, 0)`.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Thank you. I really appreciate your help.