# Visualize categorical data in R by grid

Tags: r

I have a data structure that can be imagined as this:

```
name <- c("Jim","Bob","Donald","Andy","Peter","Forest","Linda")
state <- c("AZ","CT","NY","CA","AK","CT","CA")
gender <- c("F","M","M","M","F","M","Unknown")
data <- data.frame(name,state,gender)
```

I would like to set name as row in the plot, state as column. Thus, I will have a 7*5 grid. I would like to use three colors to represent gender. Finally, the 7*5 grid are filled with color.

How can I draw the plot in R?

Comment: Something like this? `ggplot(data, aes(name, state, fill=gender))  + geom_tile()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998372/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables

Comment: Thanks! I still have another question. If a cell has several different colors, the code has trouble to visualize it. For example, name <- c("Jim","Jim", "Jim"), state <- c("AZ","AZ","AZ"), gender = c("F","M","Unknown"). How can I modify the code to let the same cell has three different colors?

Comment: How would you want that to look like? There’s no easy way to do have multiple colors in the same cell.

Comment: How about three colors in the same cell? Just like the flag of France.